# Snowflake - Primary key column is empty when importing from s3 seeing NULL result in a non-nullable column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a file that contains  id column (which is the PK in the table I'm trying to load to) and a start and end date column. Even if the file is empty and contains no id, we append a start and end date to the file.

So when I try to load the s3 file to snowflake I see:

```
NULL result in a non-nullable column
```

I've also run an alter statement on the table to drop the primary keys but I still see this error

The file I'm trying to load to snowflake:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 |

The command I'm using to load to snowflake from s3:

```
COPY INTO my_table
FROM (
    SELECT id, start_date, end_date
    FROM @s3_location/ids.csv
)
file_format = (format_name = 'file format')


TRUNCATECOLUMNS = FALSE
FORCE = FALSE
```

Comment: Please share the code for loading (or stage table DDL or what-have-you) and sample of the file that isn't loading. There isn't enough information in your question for us to be able to troubleshoot with you.

Comment: It’s a good idea to explicitly list the columns you are copying into - so it is clear what $1, $2, $3 are mapped to. If you run just the SELECT what does it return for the 3 columns? What is the DDL for your table?

Comment: hi @NickW I've updated the copy into with the 3 columns, I have them shown in the example file as well, so that is what they would look like in Snowflake if it loaded. I don't understand what you mean by just the SELECT statement

Comment: @StriplingWarrior how do I check if its required and then how do I have this removed, it isn't required for us when loading, we might now have any id's for that start and end date, but we still want to see the start and end date to make sure we ran it

Comment: "Even if the file is empty and contains no id, we append a start and end date to the file." So what do you expect to have happen to your destination table in that case? Do you want a new row to be added with an auto-generated ID? Or do you want nothing to be added?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior it will be null for id, and then we do have something for start and end date like in the file example, that's how I would like it to look like

Comment: COPY INTO will add values to the table, not replace them. So if you have two files with a single row like this, you'd end up with two rows that have the same (NULL) ID. So you need to decide between having `id` be a primary key (which shouldn't be null), or having a row added to your table with a null value. You can't do both.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I removed id as a PK and I still see this error. I ran the alter statement: ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;  then I tried to copy into again

Comment: Alter table to make that column allow null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to allow your ID column to be null.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN id DROP NOT NULL;
```

If that's true, you'll also want to stop treating it as a primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: thanks! how did it become not nullable? when I made it a PK? but then why did it reverse and become nullable after I dropped it as a PK?

Comment: Yes. If you define a column as the primary key, Snowflake will assume you want it to be NOT NULL. Oddly, it does this even if you explicitly say `NULL` in the column declaration (something I'd consider a bug). But adding and removing PK constraints after the fact will not change the `NULL`/`NOT NULL` status of the column. You have to make that change separately.